# HTML table generated with PHP

Tags: php, html-table

```
function destinations(){
    global $db;

    $numri1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE direction='1';");

        $i = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($numri1)) {
            if ($i % 2 != "0") # An odd row
              $rowColor = "bgC1";
            else # An even row
              $rowColor = "bgC2";

            $direction1 .= '<tr class="'.$rowColor.'">
                                <td>'.$i.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                            </tr>';
        $i++;
        }


$table1 =  '<table width="30%" style="margin:10px 10px 0 10px;" class="extra" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" border="0" >
            <tr class="bgC3" style="font-weight:bold;>
                <td>asd</td>
                <td>Qytetet domestike</td>
            </tr>
            '.$direction1.'
            </table>';

        return $table1;
}
```

There must be a small problem with this because when its displayed in browser it doest show this:

```
        <tr class="bgC3" style="font-weight:bold;>
            <td>asd</td>
            <td>Qytetet domestike</td>
        </tr>
```

well, it shows it but it replaces the values the "asd" and "Qytetet domestike"!

Comment: Could I suggest using CSS's `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` to alternate the row colours? What you're doing now is fine, it's just cleaner and easier to use the CSS way :-)

Comment: Is your problem in having the PHP generate the right code or having the browser display it properly? If you're having problems with the browser, you should fix your HTML - you need to close the style tag here: `<tr class="bgC3" style="font-weight:bold;>`

Comment: @JamWaffles I am not familiar with this CSS way! :) if it is from CSS3 then I am not into that yet :)

Comment: It's been around for ages. It took me quite a while to find it as well. Now that I have, it's really very handy!

Comment: `:nth-child` is from CSS3 and it's not supported by Internet Exploder < 8, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a quote at the end of your `style` attribute.

Change:

```
<tr class="bgC3" style="font-weight:bold;>
```

To:

```
<tr class="bgC3" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                         ^
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3KWQ/)? No table displayed! Now have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCBxx/).

Comment: Thank you man I knew that there was something very small in question, thank you for your time and help.